# En Laravel ¿como puedo validar un input?

Tags: laravel

Como valido un campo de formulario de este tipo

```
<select name="office[]">
```

Por la documentación, trate de validarlo así, pero no me funciona

Una forma

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'office.*' => 'required'
        ], [
            'office.required' => __('Debes agregar alguna sucursal')
        ]);
```

Otra que tampoco me funciona

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'office'   => "required|array|min:1",
            "office.*"  => "required|integer|min:1",
        ], [
            'office.*.required' => __('Debes agregar alguna sucursal')
        ]);
```

Y asi … he buscado pero no he logrado dar con la solución

Me podrían ayudar plis !!!

PD:estoy con la version 5.6.*

Comment: ¿qué es lo que tratas de validar, es decir qué es lo que quieres evitar?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba realizando un *Form Request* con

```
php artisan make:request ValidacionSelect
```

Dentro del *request* activas la validación

```
public function authorize(){
    return true;
}
```

Despues colocas las reglas que deseas

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        'office' => 'required|min:1'
    ];
}
```

Tambien puedes colocar atributos y mensajes

```
public function attributes(){
    return [
        'office' => 'Sucursal'
    ];
}
public function messages(){
    return [
        'office.required' => 'Debe agregar al menos una :attribute'
    ];
}
```

Para utilizar el *request* lo agregas en tu controlador

```
use App\Http\Requests\ValidacionSelect;
```

y despues lo colocas en tu funcion

```
public function store(ValidacionSelect $request){
}
```